# Find instances of a specific character in a string and sum up subsequent number values

Tags: javascript, string, math

Given the input string `a123~bba ....` I would like to find all instances of the letter `a`.
As you can see some `a`'s are followed by a number while some `a`'s are not. I would like to sum up all subsequent number values where `a` (followed by a different letter) is supposed to add 1 to the total sum and `a123` will add 123.

The language I'm working with is JavaScript

The code I got so far:

```js
const sol = a => {
  ac = 0;         // accumulator
  a.split``.map(
    (b,i) => {
      if (b == 'a') {
          if(/\d{3}/.test(c.slice(i+1, i+4))) {
              ac += +c.slice(i+1, i+4)
          } else {
             ac++
          }
      }
      .....
    }
    
  )
}
```

Comment: Is there a question in there?

Comment: It sounds like you're just hoping we do your homework assignment for you.

Comment: @john-jones : not asking for you to code only asking how I would go about doing this. Also not a student of programming.

Comment: Please show what you tried and explain where you're stuck. Then we can help you, rather than just providing you a solution on a plate, which is not why we're here. See [ask] as well.

Comment: `not asking for you to code only asking how I would go about doing this`...so you want an algorithm? Or what, exactly?

Comment: @ADyson : ok will add

Comment: @ADyson some reference mat for solution along with a bit of explanation of logic in JS

Comment: @ADyson : added code

Comment: @john-jones : addedcode

Comment: @Any3nymoususer: `const acc = [..."a123~bba".matchAll(/a(\d*)/g)].reduce((acc, [,r]) => acc + +(r || 1), 0);`. This will give you the result `124` since there is one `a` with 123 behind it and one `a` without a number.

Comment: @ĐinhCarabus : thanks unfortunately I cant mark ur answer as accepted :( ill go n see how this works

Comment: @Any3nymoususer, I made some edits to the question trying to clarify the intent. Perhaps it will be re-opened.

Comment: @ADyson can this question now be reopened

Comment: I didn't close it. Talk to the people who did. I can vote for it but I can't re-open it by myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function works by selecting each "a" (followed by zero or more digits) from the input string  using a regular expression. The digits are selected seperately by using a capturing group. `reduce` is then used to sum up all results from this group by first converting each selected string to an actual number using `+` (`""` will be converted to `1` first), then adding the result to the accumulator starting at `0`.

```js
const sum = (str) => [...str.matchAll(/a(\d*)/g)]
  .reduce((accu, [, digits]) => accu + +(digits || 1), 0)

console.log(sum("a123~bba"))
```